# Doubling elements of a list in f#

Tags: list, f#

I am attempting to double the elements of a given list but am getting an error "
This expression was expected to have type
    ''a list'
but here has type
    'int'
"
when defining a new list

```
let list1 = [5;10;15;20;25;30]
let rec doubleListElements list =
    match list with
    |[]-> 0
    |head::tail ->
        let doubledList = [head*2::doubleListElements tail]
        0
let printList = doubleListElements list1
printfn "%A" printList
```

I am very new to f# and don't fully understand how things work, I am more used to an object oriented approach

Comment: Helping you slightly along the way: That function is returning 0 in both branches. Obviously won't work. Also explains the error message.

Comment: I suggest you register at F# Slack if you haven't done so already. Easier to discuss things like this in such a forum. Most of us F#'ers are there I believe.

Comment: Tip: Declare the function like this: `let rec doubleListElements list : int list =` in order to get error messages that are more helpful. You can always simplify it again when the function works as expected. (Also; suggest you don't name your list list, because of possible confusion.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function in your question will work with some changes:

```
let rec doubleListElements list =
  match list with
  | [] -> []
  | head::tail -> head*2::doubleListElements tail
```

First important thing to keep in mind is "what do I want to give to and receive from this function". In your case, your input is a `int list` and desired output is an `int list`. This means wherever your function returns a value it must be an `int list`. Your function has two places where a value is returned:

```
  | [] -> [] // return empty list
  | head::tail ->
      head*2::doubleListElements tail // return a list (but recurse)
```

In your original function your return values are always `0` which of course doesn't satisfy the `int list` return type.

```
|[]-> 0 // return value
|head::tail ->
    let doubledList = [head*2::doubleListElements tail]
    0   // return value
```

In this expression, a `doubledList` is created but that value is essentially discarded because it is unused and it's not the *return value*. The return value is the final value in the expression: `0`. I think this is a very common mistake to see as people learn functional languages that are *expression-based* coming from imperative *statement-based* languages.

In this particular expression only the final value matters. In a statement-based language you might've mutated some program state before returning a value (which is also totally possible in F# but mutability is usually avoided).

```
let foo x =
  let y = x + x // the value of this expression is discarded: y is unused
  x * x         // the value of this expression is returned
```

The only other necessary change is to not wrap your returned list in another list in each recursion. `head*2::doubleListElements tail` is just a list. `[head*2::doubleListElements tail]` is the same list *inside of another list* because it's wrapped in square bracket list literals. After that change it works:

```
val printList : int list = [10; 20; 30; 40; 50; 60]
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks as well for the through explanation, that helps alot

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of different kinds of data structures, such as sequences:

```
namespace FSharpBasics

module DoubleList =

    let private list1 = [ 5; 10; 15; 20; 25; 30 ]

    (*operations*)
    let doubleList (list: List<int>) =
        Seq.init list.Length (fun index -> list.[index] * 2)
            |> Seq.toList

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        doubleList list1 
            |> printf "%A"
        System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0
```